# How to use a click function correctly for a specific purpose

Tags: javascript, math, ember.js, undefined

I am creating a small game for personal development, its a simple game of connect four and i have created my stage and set the rows and columns to 'undefined' all of this code is fully functional however in the next block-quote you should begin to understand my problem.

```
  actions: {
   start: function() {
      this.set('playing', true);
      this.set('winner', undefined);
    this.set('draw', false);
    this.set('state', [
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
    ]);
    this.set('moves', {'x': 0, 'o': 0});
    this.set('player', 'x');
    var markers = this.get('markers');
    for(var idx = 0; idx < 24; idx++) {
      markers.x[idx].visible = false;
      markers.o[idx].visible = false;
    }
    this.get('stage').update();
  }
}
```

Below is my click function which allows me to click on my grid. The markers created are placed into the clicked grid however i need the markers to drop down the column clicked on to the lowest possible row which is undefined, if it however is already !undefined then it should be in the row just above in the same column. I have added my click function below.

```
click: function(ev) {
    if(this.get('playing') && !this.get('winner')) {
        if(ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'canvas' && ev.offsetX < 
           360 && ev.offsetY < 360) {
            var x = Math.floor((ev.offsetX) / 51.5);
            var y = Math.floor((ev.offsetY) / 60);
            var state = this.get('state');
            if(!state[x][y]) {
              var player = this.get('player')
              state[x][y] = player;

          var move_count = this.get('moves')[player];
          var marker = this.get('markers')[player][move_count];
          marker.visible = true;
          if (player == 'x') {
            marker.x = 20 + x * 51.5;
            marker.y = 20 + y * 60;
          } else {
            marker.x = 20 + x * 51.5;
            marker.y = 20 + y * 60;
          }

          this.check_winner();

          this.get('moves')[player] = move_count + 1;
          if (player == 'x'){
            this.set ('player', 'o');
          } else {
            this.set('player', 'x');
          }
          this.get('stage').update();
        }
      }
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The y-coordinate of the click location does not matter. You always want to find the highest possible position. For this, simply check if there are already markers in the grid (I assume that `y=0` is the top row; if it is not, you need to reverse the loop):

```
var gridHeight = state[0].length;
for(y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
    if(state[x][y]) {
         //this cell is occupied, so choose the cell above
         break;
    }
}
y = y - 1;
```

After that, `y` holds the y-coordinate of the cell that you want to add your marker to. It can also happen that `y=-1` if the column is already full. You should handle this case and tell the user to pick again.

Here are two examples with different states:

```js
var state = [
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
    ];

function findMarkerYCoordinate(x) { 
    var gridHeight = state[0].length;
    for(y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
        if(state[x][y]) {
             //this cell is occupied, so choose the cell above
             return y - 1;
        }
    }
    return y - 1;
 }

document.write("Test on empty grid<br/>");
for(var x = 0; x < state.length; ++x)
    document.write("Position for column " + x + ": " + findMarkerYCoordinate(x) + "<br/>");
    
state = [
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 1],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 1, 1],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 1],
      [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
    ];
document.write("Test on partially filled grid<br/>");
for(var x = 0; x < state.length; ++x)
    document.write("Position for column " + x + ": " + findMarkerYCoordinate(x) + "<br/>");
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work, this only allows one column to work, dependant on what put as the number in the 'state[0].length' part.

Comment: What makes you think that this only works for a single column? `state[0].length` is just the size of the array, i.e. the grid height. If the state is a jagged array of the shape that you show in your initialization, this should work just fine.

Comment: Hi, yes, I’ve tried this in my code and it’s counting the size of my grid height as ‘7’ so when it -1 it goes to 6 however, as this ‘6’ is not an ‘undefined’ it doesn’t function properly. It only counts the specific column in state[0].length as 7 and the others remain as 6 when i check in the developer tools. Somehow it seems to be adding one to the column initially defined

Comment: I can't follow your explanations. I have added more example code to illustrate its usage. Both the example with an empty grid and a partially filled grid give the correct results (btw, there was a minor error in the code that I corrected).

Comment: Hi, thank-you for your help, I've managed to get it working now, i simply moved the 'y = y - 1' outside of the for loop and it all functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the small change made to make the code functional

```
  if(ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'canvas' && ev.offsetX < 360 && ev.offsetY < 360) {
        var x = Math.floor((ev.offsetX) / 51.5);
        var y = Math.floor((ev.offsetY));
        var state = this.get('state');
        var gridHeight = state[0].length;

          for(y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++ ) {
            if(state[x][y]) {
            //this cell is occupied, so choose the cell above
            // y = y - 1
            break;

          }
        }
        y = y - 1;
```

> The 'y = y - 1;' was moved out of the for loop and allowed the code to function correctly